# When to use Builder implementaion from Joshua Bloch, when regular one?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I am wondering when should I use builder with static class inside and where classical one?

### Implementation from Effective Java book

```
public class Pizza {
  private int size;
  private boolean cheese;
  private boolean pepperoni;
  private boolean bacon;

  public static class Builder {
    //required
    private final int size;

    //optional
    private boolean cheese = false;
    private boolean pepperoni = false;
    private boolean bacon = false;

    public Builder(int size) {
      this.size = size;
    }

    public Builder cheese(boolean value) {
      cheese = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder pepperoni(boolean value) {
      pepperoni = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder bacon(boolean value) {
      bacon = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Pizza build() {
      return new Pizza(this);
    }
  }

  private Pizza(Builder builder) {
    size = builder.size;
    cheese = builder.cheese;
    pepperoni = builder.pepperoni;
    bacon = builder.bacon;
  }
}
```

### Regular implementation

(just diagram)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say *when you are prepared to go the extra mile to make the class constructor look natural*.

Who can deny that this reads like *good code*?

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza.Builder(10).cheese(true).peperoni(true).bacon(true).build();
```

I mean ... isn't that just sweet? It's even got **bacon**!

Second (and more common) option would be:

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza(10);
pizza.setCheese(true);
pizza.setPeperoni(true);
pizza.setBacon(true);
```

This would be easier to work with using reflection and would therefore serialise/deserialise much more easily - but suffers from a more cumbersome and verbose construction.

Third and least flexible would be:

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza(10, true, true, true);
```

but it is possible to provide both 2nd and 3rd mechanism together which can be a plus.

**How to choose**

There isn't a simple way to choose. If you want to woo your customers into buying your libraries you could offer all three methods but that would then spoil one of the major the benefits of using a Builder (which is hiding the actual constructor).

I would recommend using the 2nd method and perhaps the 3rd unless there is a good reason to take the unusual route of using a Builder.

Comment: So you suggest that this implementation should be used always? Since both are in use I guess that there are cases when second one is better.

Comment: I am saying that you should use whichever is appropriate. There are times when this would be best and there are times when setters are more appropriate. The mistake is not knowing the builder method, not not using it.

Comment: When is first one appropriate and when second one? That is the question. How to analize situation and chose properly.

Answer (score 2):

*You should consider using the Builder pattern when* **1.** you need to prevent the object from getting into an inconsistent state **AND 2.** using constructor parameters would be difficult to use/read because you have an unwieldy (large) number of properties that need to be set.

Using a normal default constructor + getters/setters could allow consumers to get into an invalid/inconsistent state.  I.E. They might forget to set a very important property (like Cheese), but they aren't prevented from doing so and can create a Pizza anyway, even in a "bad" state.  The burden is on the consumer to set state on the object appropriately after construction.

You can normally prevent this via Constructor parameters.  E.G.

```
private Pizza() {}
public Pizza(int size, boolean cheese, boolean pepperoni, boolean bacon) 
{
    ...
}
```

But when you have a large number of parameters this can be difficult to read/write.

So, in summary, when you want to guarantee that your object can't be constructed in an inconsistent state AND you have too many fields to set that using constructor parameters would make it difficult to use and read, you could consider using the Builder pattern.